# SSLVerifyClient require in Cloudflare DNS

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, cloudflare

I've done setup my new domain name on Cloudflare but I have a problem while I'm setting up SSL certificate. In detail, I want ask visitors who are want to see my website content a valid certificate.

This setting working fine when I do not use CloudFlare DNS

Centos 6.7 apache config ssl `ssl.conf`

```
SSLCertificateFile server.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile server.key
SSLCACertificateFile RootCA.crt

SSLVerifyClient require
SSLVerifyDepth  10
SSLOptions +ExportCertData +StdEnvVars
```

But error when I use CloudFlare with SSL setting is full.

```
Error 525 Ray ID: 21ab2f6f25a711f5 • 2015-08-24 01:11:48 UTC
SSL handshake failed
```

How can I fix this issue?

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a fundamental problem with SSL-intercepting CDN networks.  There's no way to intercept SSL and still allow end-to-end bi-directional authentication.  If CloudFlare supported it (and, as far as I know, they don't), they could validate the client certificate at their middle point, and then pass those details through to you (in a HTTP request header, for instance).  To ensure the request was really from CloudFlare, you would want to have CloudFlare authenticate to you using another client certificate.  It all gets very complicated very quickly.

Comment: I try to disable cloud, it's working but my real server ip it isn't hidden anymore :(

Comment: Everything in life is a compromise.